# How can I get three images to animate a different image on hover using jQuery.. Code included

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

Do you see the issue with my code below? I am trying to get three different images to invoke a different image each on hover... It works great with one but something is off with adding additional... I've tried many variations with classes and IDs but I'm stuck at this point so any help is greatly appreciated.

CSS

```
.menu2 {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu2 li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}


.menu2, .1 a {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_capture_off.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2, .1 a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_capture_on.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2, .1 li em {
    background: url(images/btn_txt_capture.png) no-repeat;
    width: 218px;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}


.menu2, .2 a {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_manage_off.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2, .2 a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_manage_on.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2, .2 a li em {
    background: url(images/btn_txt_manage.png) no-repeat;
    width: 218px;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}



.menu2, .3 a {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_deliver_off.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2, .3 a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_deliver_on.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2, .3 a li em {
    background: url(images/btn_txt_deliver.png) no-repeat;
    width: 218px;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu2"> 
                    <li class="1"> 
                        <a href="#"></a>        
                        <em></em>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="2"> 
                        <a href="#"></a>
                        <em></em>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="3"> 
                        <a href="#"></a>
                        <em></em>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(".menu2 a.1").hover(function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "180"}, "slow");
                        }, function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "200"}, "fast");
                        });

                        $(".menu2 a.2").hover(function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "180"}, "slow");
                        }, function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "200"}, "fast");
                        });             

                        $(".menu2 a.3").hover(function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "180"}, "slow");
                        }, function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "200"}, "fast");
                        });
```

Comment: "URGENT" is not a free ticket to get answers.

Comment: I took the word "Urgent" out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class names from a number to something starting with a letter.

A comma in css means OR. removing the extra comma after .menu2.

Change the `$(".menu2 a.1").hover` to `$(".menu2 .someclass1 a").hover`, the `a` selector needs to come last.

seems to work.
http://www.jsfiddle.net/edKys/9/

Comment: Thanks I did try that... It enabled the regular hover overs work but the animation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!

Here is the final code

CSS

```
.menu2 {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu2 li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}


.menu2 .one a {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_capture_off.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2 .one a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_capture_on.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2 li em.one {
    background: url(images/btn_txt_capture.png) no-repeat;
    width: 218px;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}


.menu2 .two a {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_manage_off.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2 .two a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_manage_on.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2 li em.two {
    background: url(images/btn_txt_manage.png) no-repeat;
    width: 218px;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}



.menu2 .three a {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_deliver_off.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2 .three a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 218px;
    height:181px;
    background: url(images/btn_deliver_on.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.menu2 li em.three {
    background: url(images/btn_txt_deliver.png) no-repeat;
    width: 218px;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".menu2 a.one").hover(function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "180"}, "slow");
                        }, function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "200"}, "fast");
                        });

                        $(".menu2 a.two").hover(function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "180"}, "slow");
                        }, function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "200"}, "fast");
                        });             

                        $(".menu2 a.three").hover(function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show", top: "180"}, "slow");
                        }, function() {
                            $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide", top: "200"}, "fast");
                        });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menu2"> 
                    <li class="one"> 
                        <a href="#" class="one"></a>        
                        <em class="one"></em>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="two"> 
                        <a href="#" class="two"></a>
                        <em class="two"></em>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="three"> 
                        <a href="#" class="three"></a>
                        <em class="three"></em>
                    </li> 
                </ul>
```

I wanted to thank you for your answer. Later!

Comment: You can "thank" a answer by marking it as accepted. Looking on how "urgent" your question was, you should "urgently" accept a answer.